# i am trying to migrate paypal v1 to v2 rest api?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

We have a simple application where customers add Credit Cards and we generate invoices on our application and then on payment date we charge that invoice.

We are currently using PayPal v1 SDK API with v1 endpoint.
As per PayPal they have deprecated v1 endpoints and we have to upgrade to v2 endpoint. We have done some small changes using (Checkout-Java-SDK) as per PayPal but when we try to charge actual order, it failed.

Later we found out that for v2 SDK point the customer need to approve each invoice before we can charge it, is this even possible without customer involvement?

We want to shift to v2 endpoint but due to this problem we cannot change v1 to v2.

Did miss something in the process?
Can anyone suggest a solution for this problem.

Note: PayPal suggested that we should switch to Brain Tree but we don't want to use it.

Comment: This question needs more details. What problems are you having with the Checkout-Java-SDK, exactly? Creating and capturing an order via API is straightforward. Before an order can be captured, it must be approved by a payer.

Comment: but in paypal documentation is simple that change end point v1/ to v2/ and not detail about relate or approve order by a payer ?

Comment: paypal :- The /v1/payments endpoint is deprecated. Use the /v2/payments endpoint instead

Comment: v2/payments is not used to create transactions. v2/checkout/orders is used for that.

Comment: okay thanks for guidance and is that any way we can approve order programmatically without payer involvement ?